# Take screenshot of jitsi conference

Tags: webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm looking to add a `screenshot` functionality to our jitsi installation. The idea is that the `moderator` can press a button to take a `screenshot` of the video conference and the screenshot will be uploaded to our server.

Is it possible? If yes then Can someone please point me to the right direction?

I've looked at `jibri`, it allows us to record the conference, but nothing regarding `screenshot` functionality, maybe there is a way that I can grab a frame out of the video stream via a function? Is this possible? If so, how should I go about implementing it.